Move an element on another column with JavaScript
I would need that when the "header" element (class="header-content") has no elements after it in the column, it is moved directly to the next column. Is there a way to achieve this with JavaScript?
I tried with JavaScript without obtaining results


.column-list {
  border: 1px solid black;
  column-count: 2;
  column-fill: auto;
  height: 150px;
  max-width: max-content;
  column-gap: 3em;
}

.column-list li {
  break-inside: avoid;
}

.header-content {
  font-weight: bold;
  /* Stile per gli header */
}

.right {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
<ul class="column-list">
  <li class="header-content">Header 1</li>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li class="header-content">Header 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
  <li class="header-content">Header 3</li>
  <li>Item 6</li>
</ul>




post what javascript you have tried so far

it is moved directly to the next column, could you please share example scenario? I'm not quite sure I understand the question.

Are there any errors in your dev console? What does happen when you execute your javascript? What steps have you taken to debug it?

The break-after property allows you to specify that you don't want it to break into a new column directly after an element.
So add break-after: avoid; to your .header-content elements.


.column-list {
  border: 1px solid black;
  column-count: 2;
  column-fill: auto;
  height: 150px;
  max-width: max-content;
  column-gap: 3em;
}

.column-list li {
  break-inside: avoid;
}

.header-content {
  font-weight: bold;
  break-after: avoid;      
}

.right {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
<ul class="column-list">
  <li class="header-content">Header 1</li>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li class="header-content">Header 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
  <li class="header-content">Header 3</li>
  <li>Item 6</li>
</ul>



